# Difference in SocketAsyncEventArgs for services? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm building a windows service in C# to work as a server, I first built it as a regular application and it works like a charm, but when I transferred it to the service I get no connections, everything seems to be set up fine. But when I connect I get nothing, no event is triggered... Is there a difference that I need to keep in mind?

/Nick

```
public void start()
    {
            try
            {

                int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
                Int32 numConnections = DEFAULT_NUM_CONNECTIONS;
                Int32 bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;

                SocketListener sl = new SocketListener(numConnections, bufferSize, parent);

                sl.Start(port); 

                Console.WriteLine("Server listening on port {0}. Press any key to terminate the server process...", port);
                Console.Read();

                sl.Stop();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                parent.logger.WriteLogg(ex.ToString(), Logger.LoggType.Debug);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code for us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I solved it, but here is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Since the service don't do Console.Write/Read so in the  service I closed the SocketListener but in the Application it stopped at the Console.Read()